# Unity 5: how to zoom and translate an object from a grid layout to the center of the screen

Tags: unity-game-engine, grid-layout, translate-animation

I'm trying to create a scroll grid view in which every cell object is tapable.
When a cell object is tapped I want to scale and traslate it to the center of the screen and render it above other cells.
I was able to make it tapable and scale it in its position. Now I want to move the cell object to the center of the screen and render it above other cells. 
I've tried many solutions but none of them works.

This is my hierarchy:

[image]

This is the grid in normal state:

[image]

This is the grid when a cell was tapped:

[image]

I'm populating the grid from a C# script dynamically.

```
void Populate()
{
    GameObject cardContainerInstance, cardInstance;

    foreach (var c in cardsCollection.GetAll())
    {
        if (c.IsOwned)
        {
            cardContainerInstance = Instantiate(cardContainer, transform);
            cardInstance = cardContainerInstance.transform.Find("Card").gameObject;

            var cardManager = cardInstance.GetComponent<CardManager>();
            cardManager.card = c;
            cardManager.AddListener(this);
        }
        else
        {
            Instantiate(cardSlot, transform);
        }
    }

}

public void OnCardClick(GameObject cardObject, Card card)
{
    Debug.Log("OnCardClick " + card.name);

    if (openedCard != null) {
        if (openedCard.Number == card.Number)
        {
            CloseCard(openedCardObject);
        }
        else
        {
            CloseCard(openedCardObject);
            OpenCard(cardObject, card);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        OpenCard(cardObject, card);
    }
}

void OpenCard(GameObject cardObject, Card card)
{
    //cardObject.GetComponent<Canvas>().sortingOrder = 1;

    var animator = cardObject.GetComponent<Animator>();
    animator.SetTrigger("Open");

    openedCard = card;
    openedCardObject = cardObject;
}

void CloseCard(GameObject cardObject)
{
    var animator = cardObject.GetComponent<Animator>();
    animator.SetTrigger("Close");

    openedCard = null;
    openedCardObject = null;
}
```

I can't figure out how to move the cell to the center and render it above others.

Note that all is animated using an animator attached to the object itself.

Could anyone help me please? Thank you very much!

**EDIT: more details**

All cell object have the following hierarchy:

[image]

where:

- CardContainer is an empty object added to use animator on Card child object
- Card is the object itself that has a script, a canvas renderer and an animator
- StatsImage is the object that slide out when the card is tapped
- Image is a calssic UIImage with Image script, Shadow script and canvas renderer
- Other component are simple texts.

**EDIT: fix in progress**

Trying to apply [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50300757/1058278) suggestions I was able to manage the rendering order (as you see on the image below) but it seems that prevent touch events to be detected on the game object. 
I've added a GraphicsRaycaster too and now the bottom horizontal scroll view scrolls again but only if I click and drag a card.
Moreover, with the GraphicsRaycaster, the main grid card still are not clickable and it's possible to open the card only if it is behind the bottom panel (if I click on the red spot in the image below the card behind the panel receives che click)

[image]

This is the CardContainer at runtime(note that I'm attaching new Canvas and GraphicsRaycaster on the CardContainer, which is the "root" element):

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You didn't clarify whether you are using a sprite renderer or some other method but here is an answer for each.

**Sprite renderer:**

this the simple one. In each sprite renderer, there is a variable called "sortingOrder" in script and "Order in layer" in the inspector. sprite renderer with sorting Orders that are higher is rendered first. All you would need to do is call:

```
cardObject.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sortingOrder = 1;
```

when you click the card, and

```
cardObject.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sortingOrder = 0;
```

when you unclick it. I hope that makes sense!

**Other Method:**

this one is a bit harder and I would suggest that you switch to sprite renderers and it will be much easier and more stable down the road, but I can understand if you have already written a lot of scripts and don't want to go back and change them. 
Anyway, all you will need to do Is create two layers: cardLower and cardUpper. then create a new camera and call it topCamera. now under the top camera object in the inspector, change the culling mask (it's near the top) and make sure cardUpper is selected. then change the Clear flags (first one) to "Don't Clear" finally change the depth to 0 (if that doesn't work change it to -2). Now objects in the cardUpper will always be rendered above everything else. You can change the layer through script with

```
cardObject.layer = "cardUpper"
```

or

```
cardObject.layer = "cardLower"
```

I hope that helps!

Comment: I don't use the SpriteRenderer, i've updated my question with some more details. I've tried to add the SpriteRenderer to the Image component inside a card but it does not shown anything :( (I'm quitely new on Unity)

Comment: Ok, with SpriteRenderer the image is shown (i've added the spriterender on Image component and i've deactivated the default image script) but it is very very small and I can't figure out why. The sprite is imported as Tight and the sprite renderer is configured with draw mode simple. The canvas is on render mode Screen Space - Camera and the Render Camera is the Main Camera (orthgraphic). How can I fix this?

Comment: I've also tried to use two cameras as you explain and change card layer from script but when I set the layer to a card it seems to stay in the cardLower layer associated to the Main camera. In the top camera I've selected the cardUpper layer only. Is this due to Render Camera on Canvas?

Comment: OHHHHHH you are using images in the ui

Comment: thats should be super easy. Spriterenderers are essentially images for gameplay but you dont need to deal with them now

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so its pretty simple. So you are going to want to add another canvas component to the game object, and check the override sorting to true. Then use

```
cardObject.GetComponent<Canvas>().sortingOrder = 1;
```

to place it in the front and

```
cardObject.GetComponent<Canvas>().sortingOrder = 0;
```

to put it in the back.

you are also going to need to put a GraphicsRaycaster on to each of the cardObjects

Ignore my other answer about sprite renderers, they are not needed here

Comment: Thank you for your answer :) Adding Canvas componet to the CardContainer seem to be the solution but it seems to prevent touch events to be detected on the game object :( I've tried to add also EventSystem the the same gameobject but nothing changes. Also the horizontal scroll view in the lower section (under the grid) does not scroll anymore...how can I solve that?

Comment: Oh, I think adding a graphics raycaster to each of the objects should do the trick. I added that to the main answer. Also, event systems are only needed as an object somewhere in the scene. It is created by default when you add a canvas

Comment: I'm trying to add a GraphicsRaycaster as you suggest but it doesn't works compeletely. I've updated the main question with some details. Quite near the solution :)